# IIS AppPool Permission Between Servers

Tags: iis, permissions

I am having a hard time figuring out how to set permissions for an IIS web application that reads/writes files to another server.  I am currently getting Access to '\Server\Path\to\ReadWrite\' is denied.

- Server A is running IIS 6.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2 that hosts the web application.
- Server B is also 2008 R2 and contains a share folder that needs permission applied for Server A to read and write to it (Using UNC paths).
- Both servers reside within the same domain.

Typically, I would specify IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolName to give permissions, but it does not appear to be getting found from the context of Server B.  I have tried 'Everyone' too, and even that appears not to work (not that this is what I would want to use).

Answer (score 4):

Here's one option:-

- For the IIS website on Server A, have the AppPool run under a domain account
- For the UNC share on Server B, allow read & write permissions for the domain account

Here's another option, which may be useful:-

- For the IIS website on Server A, write the file to a specific path on the server
- Setup DFS-R to replicate the data from Server A to Server B

Comment: Your initial option implementing a domain account tied to the AppPool worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Versions of IIS 7.5 and later create a virtual app pool user account running under the umbrella of **ApplicationPoolIdentity**. This will be unique to that app pool and therefore won't be the same account as on another server.

You'll need to have the same specific domain user account set as having permissions against both the shared folder and the app pool. Create a new domain account specifically for this task.

You can then set this user as the app pool account by going to the Advanced Settings of the relevant App Pool, choose Identity and select to use a Custom Account. In here enter the relevant domain account name and password.

You'll also need to give that domain user permissions to access IIS and access that folder. So likely the user will need to be in the IIS_IUSRS group as well as USERS.

Give the same user permissions on the shared folder too.

Be aware that there are limitations on the the number of concurrent SMB/UNC connections due to [outbound TCP port limitations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd296694%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). There are limits that you can increase be changing some registry values. If you start getting 500 errors do some research on max TCP ports.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem on 2 servers in the same domain and both with Windows 2012 server. A web service on server A wanted to access data on server B via a UNC path like `\\SERVER_B\C$\Users\Public\MyData`.

First I’ve granted server A full access on the data ‘MyData’ on server B.
When I tried the web service running under `ApplicationPoolIdentity`, I couldn’t get access. Also running the web service with other built-in accounts like `NetworkService` and `LocalSystem`. I’ve got no access.

Then I tried an custom account and granted full access, but even that wasn’t successful.
Eventually I did get access while accessing the data via a share `MyData$` on Server B which corresponds to `C:\Users\Public\MyData`.

It seems that the use of `C$` has some restrictions.